# preventing ckeditor converts (c) to copyright and (e) to euro symbol

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using ckeditor for my text area input. I want to prevent ckeditor from converting '(c)' to the copyright symbol and '(e)' to the euro symbol

Comment: Which version of CKEditor are you using? Do you mean that when you type `(c)` it is converted to © ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config file

```
config.entities = false;
```

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't find any other way